# Can a $CX_{1,2}\cdot CX_{2,1}$ be synthesised to some $CU$ plus local gates?

Tags: quantum-circuit, gate-synthesis

[image]

Can the above circuit be synthesised to an operation where there is only one control qubit? I.e. a controlled-unitary gate, eventually surrounded by local gates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't.

The easiest way to determine this for an arbitrary operation is to compute its [KAK decomposition](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0507171). Only operations that have at most one non-zero interaction coefficient can be performed by at most one controlled operation. If you're limited to CNOT or CZ (as opposed to the full range of CPHASE(t)) then the non-zero coefficient must be maximum ($\pi/4$).

You can use cirq to compute KAK decompositions, and confirm that CNOT*NOTC has two non-zero interaction coefficients and therefore requires multiple controlled gates:

```
import cirq
a, b = cirq.LineQubit.range(2)
print(cirq.kak_decomposition(cirq.Circuit(
    cirq.CX(a, b),
    cirq.CX(b, a),
)))
```

```
KAK {
    xyz*(4/π): 1, 1, 0
    before: (0.826*π around -0.679*X+0.281*Y+0.679*Z) ⊗ (0.75*π around Z)
    after: (-0.25*π around Z) ⊗ (-0.826*π around 0.679*X+0.281*Y-0.679*Z)
}
```

The line `xyz*(4/π): 1, 1, 0` is the interaction coefficients.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a visual representation:

```
from weylchamber import c1c2c3, WeylChamber
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.cx(0,1)
qc.cx(1,0)

coord = c1c2c3(Operator(qc).data)
w = WeylChamber()
w.add_point(*coord)
w.plot()
```

This confirms to us that your circuit is actually an iSWAP (A2) + local gates.

[image: Weyl Chamber plot]

Comment: Please add further details on what you are calculating and why.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. It is indeed true that my example relates to the iSWAP operator. Here an easy way to see it: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.iSwapGate.html. We would appreciate further details on your way to answer the question!

Comment: Using the KAK decomposition, each 2Q unitary has a set of 3 parameters invariant to local 1Q gates before and after the 2Q gate. The Weyl Chamber is a plot of these invariants in a coordinate space (up to some normalization, and simplification due to commutation rules). 

Every 2Q gate maps to a coordinate in the Weyl Chamber, so take the target unitary, CX + XC, find its coordinate and plot it. Craig shows the invariants are (1, 1, 0), but on my plot I use a different normalization, the invariants are $(\pi/2, \pi/2, 0)$.

Whereas C(U) gates are in the chamber between 0 and A_1.